# mvvm light - messaging ( VS "tab friendly" class )

Tags: c#, mvvm-light

I have a msgClass looking like this for all my appMessages ( using mvvm light messenger )

```
public static class AppMessages
{
    enum MessageTypes
    {
        changeStateMsg,
        inputMsg
    }

    public class MsgBase
    {
        public static void unRegister(object recipient)
        {
            Messenger.Default.Unregister<bool>(recipient);
        }
    }

    public static class changeState : MsgBase
    {
        public static void Send(bool stateChange)
        {
            Messenger.Default.Send<bool>(stateChange, MessageTypes.changeStateMsg);
        }

        public static void Register(object recipient, Action<bool> action)
        {
            Messenger.Default.Register<bool>(recipient, MessageTypes.changeStateMsg, action);
        }
    }

    public static class inputMsg : MsgBase
    {
        public static void Send(string key)
        {
            Messenger.Default.Send<string>(key, MessageTypes.inputMsg);
        }

        public static void Register(object recipient, Action<string> action)
        {
            Messenger.Default.Register<string>(recipient, MessageTypes.inputMsg, action);
        }
    }
}
```

Just wandered if is possible to make it more VS tab friendly  I´am registrating it like this :

```
AppMessages.changeState.Register(this, onStateChange );
```

My question is how can I make it auto-generate the onStateChange method ( rightClicking only makes me able to make a property/field )

So its a "being lazy question" I know I should only write this :

```
 public void onStateChange(bool b)
    { 
    }
```

But if any of you know how to autogenerate it ?? I whould be happy  :)

/cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a limitation of VS. Resharper on the other hand is able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), but you have to buy a license to use it. After using it for almost 3 years I can highly recommend it to you. (You can download trial version and see how it works)